# scikit-learn error: libquadmath.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I got this erreur when I've tried to import scikit learn to my python 3.5 (jupyter notebook):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-139cc3505715> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

/opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-4.2.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py in <module>()
     55 else:
     56     from . import __check_build
---> 57     from .base import clone
     58     __check_build  # avoid flakes unused variable error
     59 

/opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-4.2.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in <module>()
     10 from scipy import sparse
     11 from .externals import six
---> 12 from .utils.fixes import signature
     13 from .utils.deprecation import deprecated
     14 from .exceptions import ChangedBehaviorWarning as _ChangedBehaviorWarning

/opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-4.2.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in <module>()
      9 
     10 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
---> 11 from .validation import (as_float_array,
     12                          assert_all_finite,
     13                          check_random_state, column_or_1d, check_array,

/opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-4.2.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in <module>()
     16 
     17 from ..externals import six
---> 18 from ..utils.fixes import signature
     19 from .deprecation import deprecated
     20 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning as _DataConversionWarning

/opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-4.2.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py in <module>()
    289     from ._scipy_sparse_lsqr_backport import lsqr as sparse_lsqr
    290 else:
--> 291     from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr
    292 
    293 

/opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-4.2.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/__init__.py in <module>()
    110 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    111 
--> 112 from .isolve import *
    113 from .dsolve import *
    114 from .interface import *

/opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-4.2.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 
      5 #from info import __doc__
----> 6 from .iterative import *
      7 from .minres import minres
      8 from .lgmres import lgmres

/opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-4.2.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/iterative.py in <module>()
      5 __all__ = ['bicg','bicgstab','cg','cgs','gmres','qmr']
      6 
----> 7 from . import _iterative
      8 
      9 from scipy.sparse.linalg.interface import LinearOperator

ImportError: libquadmath.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

the scikit learn 0.18.2 package is already installed and I can see it on the list when I run `conda list`(I got the same error with the last version 0.19.1).

I work with the Anaconda 3 (conda 4.2.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'r python installation has missing dynamically linked shared library which is used by scipy.

generally when you install anaconda under lib directory this shared objects are present and respective paths are exported in environment for dynamic linking.

check if this files are there under the lib directory of your anaconda installation.

e.g:- 
/anaconda3/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib

if it is not there then please reinstall anaconda it will solve your problem. 
if this file exists then please check your environment path. which must have anaconda installation path in there list.